# LCD follows commands but doesn't display characters

Tags: c, microcontroller, lcd

I have programmed an Atmega-16 Microcontroller to interface a LM016L LCD display. The program is as follows:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#define MrLCDsCrib PORTB
#define DataDir_MrLCDsCrib DDRB
#define MrLCDsControl PORTD
#define DataDir_MrLCDsControl DDRD
#define LightSwitch 5
#define ReadWrite 7
#define BiPolarMood 2

void Check_IF_MrLCD_isBusy(void);
void Peek_A_Boo(void);
void Send_A_Command(unsigned char command);
void Send_A_Character(unsigned char character);

int main(void) {
    DataDir_MrLCDsControl |= 1 << LightSwitch | 1 << ReadWrite | 1 << BiPolarMood;
    _delay_ms(15);

    Send_A_Command(0x01); //Clear Screen 
    _delay_ms(20);
    Send_A_Command(0x38); //8-bit mode
    _delay_ms(20);
    Send_A_Command(0b00001110); // cursor on
    _delay_ms(20);
    Send_A_Command(0x0F); // cursor blinking
    _delay_ms(20);

    Send_A_Character(0x4E); //N
    _delay_ms(20);
    Send_A_Character(0x65); //e
    _delay_ms(20);
    Send_A_Character(0x77); //w
    _delay_ms(20);


    while (1) {}
}

void Check_IF_MrLCD_isBusy() {
    DataDir_MrLCDsCrib = 0;
    MrLCDsControl |= 1 << ReadWrite;
    MrLCDsControl &= ~1 << BiPolarMood;

    while (MrLCDsCrib >= 0x80) {
        Peek_A_Boo();
    }
    DataDir_MrLCDsCrib = 0xFF;
}

//Peek_A_Boo() writes the data to or from the LCD that are waiting to be written 
void Peek_A_Boo() {
    MrLCDsControl |= 1 << LightSwitch;
    asm volatile("nop");
    asm volatile("nop");
    MrLCDsControl &= ~1 << LightSwitch;
}

void Send_A_Command(unsigned char command) {
    Check_IF_MrLCD_isBusy();
    MrLCDsCrib = command;
    MrLCDsControl &= ~ ((1 << ReadWrite) | (1 << BiPolarMood));
    Peek_A_Boo();
    MrLCDsCrib = 0;
}

void Send_A_Character(unsigned char character) {
    Check_IF_MrLCD_isBusy();
    MrLCDsCrib = character;
    MrLCDsControl &= ~ (1 << ReadWrite);
    MrLCDsControl |= 1 << BiPolarMood;
    Peek_A_Boo();
    MrLCDsCrib = 0;
}
```

When I send commands to the LCD like making the cursor to blink, it works perfectly fine. But when the function Send_A_Character() is called to write the characters to the screen, it doesn't work. I cannot make LCD to display anything on the screen. There is no syntax error on the above code. If anyone of you could point out a logical error that is preventing LCD to display anything on the screen, that would be great. I've even tried increasing the delays at each points to 2 seconds but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you post a link to a PDF schematic and some links to the data sheets for your uC and the LCD?

Comment: Link for LCD datasheet: [link]http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/146552/HITACHI/LM016L.html

Comment: Link for Microcontroller datasheet: [link]http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2466.pdf

Comment: Please put that information in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I spent hours on this code and couldn't make it work.
However I managed to write stuff on my LCD as follows:

1. You need to connect RW of the LCD to GND of the MCu
2. Modify other connections according to code as well.
3. Here's the code that worked for me:
   (http://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/lcd-interfacing-with-atmega32-avr)

   ```
   // Code for LCD Interfacing with ATmega32 AVR microcontroller
   #include <avr/io.h>
   #define F_CPU 1000000UL
   #include <util/delay.h>
   #define RS 6
   #define E  5
   void send_a_command (unsigned char command);
   void send_a_character(unsigned char character);
   int main(void)
   {
       DDRA = 0xFF;
       DDRD = 0xFF;
       _delay_ms(50);
       send_a_command(0x01);// sending all clear command
       send_a_command(0x38);// 16*2 line LCD
       send_a_command(0x0E);// screen and cursor ON

        send_a_character (0x44); // ASCII(American Standard Code for Information Interchange) code for 'D'
        send_a_character (0x49); // ASCII(American Standard Code for Information Interchange) code for 'I'
        send_a_character (0x4C); // ASCII(American Standard Code for Information Interchange) code for 'L'
        send_a_character (0x49); // ASCII(American Standard Code for Information Interchange) code for 'I'
        send_a_character (0x50); // ASCII(American Standard Code for Information Interchange) code for 'P'

   }
   void send_a_command (unsigned char command)
   {
       PORTA=command;
       PORTD&= ~(1<<RS);
       PORTD|= (1<<E);
       _delay_ms(50);
       PORTD&= ~(1<<E);
       PORTA =0;
   }
   void send_a_character (unsigned char character)
   {
       PORTA=character;
       PORTD|= (1<<RS);
       PORTD|= (1<<E);
       _delay_ms(50);
       PORTD&= ~(1<<E);
       PORTA =0;
   }
   ```

Comment: If you click on the "edited Dec 9" text, you can see the small changes that were needed to properly format your post. There is help available when editing. Cheers, and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

If the LCD executes the commands correctly and fails to display characters then you need to check two things: Connection of the RS pin. Recall that for commands, the RS should be low meaning that even with a bad connection commands will still run. You need to confirm that the RS is indeed a high and is connected correctly. I had the same issue and it took me a day to realize that indeed i had interchanged the RS and RW connections to the LCD. The data pins are correct so long as they send the commands to the LCD. Hope that helps :)